# Best way to create Android widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to develop some android widgets.I need to make it stylish and should support multi-screen resolutions.
I developed some widgets but had problems with screen-resolution.

What are best methods to create these?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: can you tell us what are your problems?

Comment: It seem to be your problem is **screen resolution**. Please read it once, i hope it may help you.[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I applied a background image to my widget,this image gets affected when screen resolution varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for  screen-resolution , normal android design guidelines are necessary and sufficient because widget also follows xml layout techniue ,difference comes with `remoteView` methods only ,which has nothing to do with design .

about implementation i will say extending `AppWidgetProvider` is better then a `broadcastReceiver` approach to update widget contents .